# Multiple MSI interrupt failing

Tags: interrupt, interrupt-handling, pci, pci-e

I am currently running this pci test :

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/PCI/endpoint/pci-test-howto.html

My test is working fine for following test:

pcitest -m 1

but failing for other interrupts. e.g.

pcitest -m 2  (or 3,4,5...32)

On further debugging, I found that ISR is getting called twice for msi > 1.
One for msi == 1 and other for msi > 1.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Misunderstanding what MSI is?

Comment: MSI : Message Signal Interrupt.

Comment: You can ask the author how it is being configured.